# I am getting an error when importing pycoingecko

Tags: python, importerror, coingecko

```
!pip install pycoingecko

from pycoingecko import CoingeckoAPI
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0df3e3f44200> in <module>
----> 1 from pycoingecko import CoingeckoAPI

ImportError: cannot import name 'CoingeckoAPI' from 'pycoingecko' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycoingecko\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://pypi.org/project/pycoingecko/:

> Usage
>
> ```
> from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
> cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
> ```

You need to use `CoinGeckoAPI`, not `CoingeckoAPI`.